# Jquery : Why is the first image repeated twice in lightbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I'm new to Jquery and PHP. With the below code, I see the first image gets repeated twice, while the rest of the images are displayed properly.

```
 <div class="image-zoom" rel="lightbox" id="gallery">
        <div id="album1" style="margin-right:18px;" rel="lightbox">
            <?php
            if (isset($albums[0])) {
                $i = 1;
                foreach ($albums[0]['photos'] as $photo) {
                    if ($i == 1) {
                        ?>
                        <a href="<?= $photo ?>" rel="lightbox">
                            <img src="<?= $photo ?>" width="214" height="160" />
                        </a>
                        <div class="zoom-magnifier" id="gallery">
                            <a href="<?= $photo ?>" rel="lightbox">
                                <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl; ?>/images/zoom-icon.png" id="zoom"/>
                            </a>
                            <div id="more-text" align="left" ><?=$albums[0]['title']?></div>
                        </div>
                        <?php

                    } else {
                        ?>
                        <a href="<?= $photo ?>" rel="lightbox"></a>
                        <?php
                    }
                    $i++;
                }              
            }
            ?>
        </div>
        <div id="album2" rel="lightbox">
            <?php
            foreach (array(1, 0) as $album_id) {
                if (isset($albums[$album_id])) {
                    $i = 1;
                    foreach ($albums[$album_id]['photos'] as $photo) {
                        if ($i == 1) {
                            ?>
                            <a href="<?= $photo ?>" rel="lightbox">
                                <img src="<?= $photo ?>" width="214" height="160" />
                            </a>
                            <div class="zoom-magnifier">
                                <a href="<?= $photo ?>" rel="lightbox">
                                    <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl; ?>/images/zoom-icon.png" id="zoom1"/>
                                </a>
                                <div id="more-text2" class="more-txt-link"><?=$albums[$album_id]['title']?></div>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                        } else {
                            ?>
                            <a href="<?= $photo ?>" rel="lightbox"></a>
                            <?php
                        }
                        $i++;
                    }                        
                    break;
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Below is the code of lightbox script.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl; ?>/js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl; ?>/css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#album1 a').lightBox();
        $('#album2 a').lightBox();
    });
</script>
```

So if there are 5 images to be displayed, with the above code I get 6 images displayed with the first image repeated twice.
How can I avoid this

Comment: do you need the ` rel="lightbox"` on the `div` ?

Comment: Yes ...It is already in the code. I cannot change it

Comment: One way to debug would be to take the generated html, and create a fiddle out of it.

Comment: Which means to use http://jsfiddle.net/ to create a tiny online demo containing just the code that isn't working. This would let other people work with your code too.